# SQL Server - Inserting Dummy Records within a date and time frame

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm having a tough time figuring out an issue I'm working on. In short I'm attempting to account for missing data (for metrics reports).

Ex. I'm expecting 12 results per server per 15 min window, when that number isn't met i'd like to insert a record that is simply labeled as Missing with a date and time that corresponds to the missing record on the table.

Is anyone familiar with a scrip that can count batches an insert where a specific number (in this case 12) is not met to meet that goal?

Lets say my table is set up as such:

```
ID   Server   Uptime   CheckTime   Checkdate   Status

1    test1    100       12:15       1/1/13     GOOD

2    test2    100       12:15       1/1/13     BAD

3    test4    100       12:15       1/1/13     GOOD
```

In this case only 3 markers were returned when I am expecting 12. How could I generate the remaining 9 records without a manual process and mark them as missing? The specific ID's aren't that important, the relevant data would be Server, Checkdate, Checktime, and Status.

The idea im thinking so far is something along the lines of this:

```
dbo.tbluptime = a
dbo.tblreportingtabletest = b

Select missing, SERVER, checkdate, checktime from a 

X=a.missing

insert X rows into B
Values (MISSING, a.server, a.checkdate, a.checktime)
where b.server=a.server and b.checkdate=a.checkdate and b.checktime=a.checktime
```

Formatting and syntax nonwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Select the count of your records that meet your timeframe, (in this case, 3), then take your "expectedCount" (which is 12) and subtract your count (3) from that. Then do an insert that many times...

Comment: This seems like a very manual process and while it may work I would be doing this over a stretch of tens of thousands of rows all with separate 15 min time blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that generates missing records:

```
with n as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from n
      where n <= 12
     ),
     dt as (
      select top 1 checktime, checkdate
      from t
     )
select NULL as id, NULL as server, NULL as uptime, dt.checktime, dt.checkdate,
       'MISSING' as status
from n cross join dt
where n.n <= 12 - (select count(*) from t)
union all
select *
from t;
```